# Custom ScrollBar styling artifact?

Tags: c#, wpf

What is this rectangle and how to get rid of it?

[image]

I am only templating scrollbars:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF07468B"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <!-- thumb is defined somewhere -->
                            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"/>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false"/>
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                             <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false"/>
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
                <!-- removed triggers -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I doubt if it's a `ScrollBar`, more like `ListBox` itself. The problem only appears when horizontal scrollbar is visible.

---

To example, [here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1525/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx) guy templating `ScrollViewer` and as you can see image is without artefact or *intersection* (or resizegrip, or whatever).

Do I need to do something to `ListBox` when only templating scrollbars? And what exactly it will be?

[image]

---

Making `ListBox` background `Red` will produce following:

[image]

So this rectangle is something `LightGray`, but from where it comes from?

Comment: Maybe a ResizeGrip? Is your image showing a whole window or just a list with scrollbars?

Comment: The rectangle appears because that is the intersection of `Horizontal Bar` and `Vertical Bar`. It is just a style/design issue.

Comment: @SJD, see update, what exactly issue do you mean?

Comment: what do you expect to see instead of the rectangle? I'll try to prepare a sample for that.

Comment: @Sinatr it depends, for instance on Windows 7 that "intersection" doesn't exists as a solid color (solid instance) but if you run the application in Windows 8/8.1 you'll see that the rectangle is not transparent but it is gray (scroll bar color). See Windows 8 style : https://www.dropbox.com/s/90gig6au425t9la/Screenshot%202014-06-11%2015.14.48.png. Also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527758/change-background-color-of-scrollbar-in-scrollviewer-wpf (I'm sure you've already checked it). I guess the best solution is to change the proper scrollBar style)

Comment: @SJD, still can't understand you. Dropbox link is broken. Can you post your solution as an answer please (that `proper` scrollBar style)?

Comment: I also recommend solution to customize scrollbar from this link http://www.nullskull.com/a/1525/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx, coincidentally the two images here are posted in that link too.

Comment: @pushpraj, I would expect, what `ListBox` let me freely re-style `ScroollBars` without mentioned *intersection* issues, etc.

Comment: intersection is part of design it can't be removed, you can find it everywhere in windows, even in the browser in which you are reading this comment. All what we can do it to opt for style scrollbars for a nice appearance eg. android or windows phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style of a "normal" `scrollBar` in a `listBox` or in a window is generic.

You cannot change the style as you want! This is a small detail that *probably* nobody thought about it.

**Why do you see that rectangle?**

Well, I guess the guys from Microsoft had this three possibilities:

**1.** Horizontal bar fills the intersection.

[image]

**2.** Vertical bar fills the intersection

[image]

**3.** Or there is a solid rectangle which has the same color as the proper scrollBar.

[image]

So, they decided to use the 3rd option. And also as I said, without ***changing*** the whole style of a scrollBar you **cannot** change that small detail. Maybe you can change with this style : http://www.nullskull.com/a/1525/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx ?:D

Comment: Now is clear. Thanks! Your last screenshot is *obviously* (at least for me) wanted behavior. Should I restyle `Listbox` (looking now [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242.aspx)) by adding my `ScrollViewer` or what exactly do I have to do (that article doesn't say a word about `ListBox`)?

Comment: @Sinatr once you create your style you can bind that style to your `ListBox` scrollViewer. Just like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909602/silverlight-style-scrollviewer-for-listbox

Comment: You was right. Custom `ScrollViewer` is the right way to go.